# value of $\alpha$ in rational expression.

Tags: trigonometry

> For all real values of $x\;,$ Given that $$\frac{4x^2+1}{64x^2-96x\sin \alpha+5}<\frac{1}{32}\;,$$ Then $\alpha$ lie in the interval

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ We can write it as $$\frac{32(4x^2+1)-(64x^2-96x\sin \alpha+5)}{32(64x^2-96x\sin \alpha+5)}<0$$

So $$\frac{64x^2+96x\sin \alpha+27}{64x^2-96x\sin \alpha+5}<0$$

Now Using Completing square method, We get $$\frac{64\left(x+\frac{3}{4}\sin \alpha\right)^2+27-36\sin^2\alpha}{64\left(x-\frac{3}{4}\sin \alpha\right)^2+5-36\sin^2\alpha}<0$$

Now how can i solve aftert that, Help required, Thanks

Comment: you have done something wrong in main question

Comment: Thanks  Archis Welankar, I have edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\frac{64x^2+96x\sin \alpha+27}{64x^2-96x\sin \alpha+5}<0$, *for all values* of $x$, clearly, the numerator and denominator can not have real roots (if they have, there is at least one value of $x$ for which both the numerator and denominator will have same sign).

Since both the numerator and denominator are parabolas with vertex downwards (like $y=x^2)$, either they are always positive or have both positive and negative values. Hence for no value of $\alpha$ the given inequality holds for *all values of* $x$.

When $36\sin^2\alpha - 5 < 0$, then for all $x$, the inequality
\begin{equation*}
\frac{4x^2+1}{64x^2-96x\sin \alpha+5} \geq \frac{1}{32}
\end{equation*}
holds.

Answer (score 0):

Hint take the quadratic equation note I am assuming it's $96x\sin(\alpha)$. So we get $64x^2+96x\sin(\alpha)+27<0$ thus discriminant should be less than $0$ thus $9612\sin^2(\alpha)<6912$ thus range of $\alpha$ is ..

Comment: But how can we say $64x^2-96x\sin \alpha+5>0$

Comment: No I have simplified the original question by cross multiplying not the one you simplified to